# Random <li> tag generated by browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, html-lists

I am making a form in a `<ul>` tag that I have yet to finish.
The HTML I have so far is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Contact &mdash; Schwiesow &amp; Drilias</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/css/main.css" />

        <script src="res/js/libraries/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bg_img"></div>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <div id="navigation_button">
                <a href="#main_navigation" id="open_nav">&equiv;</a>
                <a href="#" id="close_nav">&equiv;</a>
            </div>
            <div id="title">
                <img src="res/images/logo.sd.png" alt="Schwiesow &amp; Drilias" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav id="main_navigation">
            <span class="header">Schwiesow &amp; Drilias</span>
            <a href="/m/sd/">Profile</a>
            <a href="/m/sd/projects/">Projects</a>
            <a href="/m/sd/press.html">Press</a>
            <span class="header">The Garden Room</span>
            <a href="/m/gr/">Profile</a>
            <a href="/m/gr/press.html">Press</a>
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            <a href="/m/sd/contact.php">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">
            <ul>
                <li class="input"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><li>
                <li class="input"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></li>
                <li class="message"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea></li>
                <li class="button"><input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, both Safari and Chrome insert a random `<li></li>` after the first one.
Here is a screenshot.[image]

It's very annoying as it causes a large space between the first and second `<li>` because the style is set to `height: 50px;`

Comment: Just as a reference, the browser should not be generating any type of extra code. The only way this could potentially happen is through JavaScript or accidental use of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is missing the terminating "/" on the closing `<li>` tag

`<li class="input"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><li>`

Your browser is terminating it for you, as well as the one you *should* be terminating in the first place.

Comment: Note that list items have optional end tags, so `<li><li>` is valid markup for 2 list items.

Comment: Yes, however, the OP has opted to use the style of closing the opening tags, which is resulting in the undesired behavior. I merely called attention to that being the reason why.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I ran it first through the HTML validator and that error was not returned. I just wasn't looking close enough!

Answer (score 0):

The first `<li>` doesn't have a closing tag. it's `<li><li>` instead of `<li></li>`